# Google Places Autocomplete API not returning result for some locations

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, google-api, google-places-api

Google places autocomplete API not giving search result for some locations. When I search in Google it returns the location name in `search hint`.

Below are some example locations :

- Comfort Inn Manhattan, new york city, new york
- Radisson Martinique, new york city, new york

Has anyone faced this? Any work around in iOS and/or android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting a parameter `types=geocode` which restricted places to location/addresses. i.e. gym, restaurants, etc... would not be returned in result.

Removing the parameter from url solved issue.